# Ambiguous values on OSM to calculate optimal path: Which value should I use?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting, astar

I'm using San Francisco OSM dataset, I want to calculate the optimal path using pgrouting(pgr_astar)
The problem that I don't know which column should I use?
For example:
I want to calculate the optimal path from Cesar Chavez Street to Tewksbury Avenue, which value of wich line should I use as source and target id?

Cesar Chavez Street:
[image]

Tewksbury Avenue:

[image]

For Cesar Chavez Street for example i have 115 street with the same name which one should I use and which value?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For pgRouting functions you need to use the attributes that define your network topology. The network pgRouting uses has road links (unique `id`) with start and end node ID's (`source` and `target` node), so in your query you probably use those.

`osm_id` is the original OSM ID, so you have a reference to your original data. The grey column on the left is just a row number of your table viewer, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for answering. And concerning the lines do you have an idea which of the lines should I use (several lines have the same name as the initial segement as well as the final segement)